# How do I solve $\int\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}\ dx$ without using Weierstass Substitution?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

Every problem that I've put into wolfram alpha lately gives me instructions to substitute $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$, but I haven't been taught how to do that, nor can I understand how it works anyhow...

Comment: This falls under the category $\cos^m x\sin^n x$ where $m$ and $n$ are integers, not necessarily positive. Say $m$ is odd. Then some manipulation and the substitution $u=\sin x$ lead to the integral of a rational function.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution which really is a helpful thing to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$ \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)} \; \mathrm dx$$

You should know the Pythagorean Identity:

$$ \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1 $$

So:

$$ \int \frac{1 - \sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)} \; \mathrm dx$$
$$ \int \left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)} - \sin(x) \right) \; \mathrm dx$$
$$ \int \left(\csc(x) - \sin(x)\right) \; \mathrm dx $$
$$ \int \csc(x) \; \mathrm dx - \int \sin(x) \; \mathrm dx $$

---

There is a nice little explanation of the Weierstrass Substitution [here](http://www.westga.edu/~faucette/research/Miracle.pdf). Basically, any function using $\sin$ and $\cos$ can be expressed as rational functions of $\tan(x/2)$, so you can then easily integrate most integrals by method of partial fractions (the paper linked goes further than that).

Comment: Indeed I should have known that... I'm starting to think that my brain is going numb from all the trig integrals I've done. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 10):

Here's one approach.
First rewrite the integral as
$$
\int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)} dx
= \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} \sin(x) dx
= \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)} \sin(x) dx .
$$
Using the substitution $u = \cos(x)$, this becomes
$$
- \int \frac{u^2}{1-u^2} du ,
$$
which can now be computed by using partial fractions.
I'll leave the rest of the details to you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

write this integral as $$ \int \frac{1 - \sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)} \; \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)} \mathrm dx = \int \csc(x) \; \mathrm dx  - \int \sin(x) \; \mathrm dx $$